# Troubles with code for upload a image

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, attachments, uploads

can someone give me please a code for image upload ? i try many but no one works , this is what i have :

```
    $post = array(
              'comment_status' => $comment_status,
              'ping_status'    => 'open',
              'post_author'    => $user_id,
              'post_content'   => '',
              'post_status'    => $status,
              'post_title'     => $title,
              'post_type'      => 'post',
             );  
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);



    if($_FILES['image_imagepost']['error'] == 0) {

            function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false'){

// check to make sure its a successful upload
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attach_id = ( $file_handler, $post_id );

if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
return $attach_id;
            }
```

I try to make a post and upload a image,the post is ok but the image didin't upload on media.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it ;-)

Comment: i did it but i can't accept it, why?

Comment: O crap yes, there is a stupid 48 hour restriction. You will only be ably able to accept your own answer in 2 days ;-)

Comment: Ok , i will do that if i rembember :D

Answer (score 0):

well i look and i look and finally i found this work that work for me.

```
    $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['image']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) );

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );

    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ),
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $upload['file'] )),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['file'], $post_id );

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );

    wp_redirect( site_url() . '/thank-you/' );

    die();
}
```

from  [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/upload-file-functions/)